# Is using same key pair for both encryption and signing secure in RSA

Tags: rsa, oaep

In GPG, we can use same key pair for encryption and signing. Can't/Shouldn't we do this in RSA. I am using  RSAES-OAEP and RSASSA-PSS, not raw RSA btw.